Find the minimum and maximum values of $f(P ) = \angle ABP + \angle BCP + \angle CDP + \angle DAP$

Let $P$ be a point inside or on the boundary of a square $ABCD$. Find the minimum and maximum values of $f(P ) = \angle ABP + \angle BCP + \angle CDP + \angle DAP$.


calling the angles $a,b,c,d$ if none of them are 0, then we can apply the AM GM inequality to get $a+b+c+d \geq 4(abcd)^{1/4}$, but how to get the lowest value of this expression then?

Why downvote please explain

Note that AM-GM likely won't be helpful here, since equality holds when all terms are equal, which implies that the angles are all $45^\circ$ and doesn't give us the min or max. Also, multiplying angles doesn't seem like the right step to take.

@CalvinLin but why doesn't it work here? Shouldn't 45° give us minimum which is also achievable? Why is it wrong to use AM-GM here?

No, the min is almost certainly not $ 4 \times 45 ^ \circ = 180^\circ$, as that would imply that $f(P)$ is a constant. $\quad$ Naive AM-GM is not necessarily "wrong", just unlikely to be, because the minimum doesn't happen when all terms are equal. IE If the equality condition is not satisfied, then at best you have an infimum but not a minimum. (whereas since this is a continuous function on a compact space, we know that the minimum definitely occurs). Having said that, there might be a funky way of applying AM-GM to solve this problem.

Maybe some roations of point $P$ can be helpful since we will obtain some right angles

Use GeoGebra to get a sense how it looks like.

See this question for an answer using complex numbers

After many attempts, I think I can use some algebraic methods to solve this problem, but I really cannot give you a geometrical proof, which is too hard for me. The answer of this problem is that $\displaystyle \frac{3\pi}{4}<f(P)<\frac{5\pi}{4}.$ I will only show $\displaystyle f(P)<\frac{5\pi}{4}$ because we can use a very similar method to prove $\displaystyle f(P)>\frac{3\pi}{4}$.
First, I think one key difficulty in dealing with this problem is that it's always hard to put four almost irrelevant angles together and find any geometrical relations between them, especially when we're dealing with the sum. However, one tool is quite efficient in dealing with the sum of angles, which is the complex number. Recall the famous identity $$r_1(\cos\theta_1+i\sin\theta_1)\cdot r_2(\cos\theta_2+i\sin\theta_2)=r_1r_2\big(\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)+i\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)\big),$$ it then becomes quite straightforward to find four complex nubmers for $\angle ABP$, $\angle BCP$, $\angle CDP$, $\angle DAP$ respectively. Now if we put point $A$ at the origin, $B$ at $(1,0)$, $C$ at $(1,1)$, $D$ at $(0,1)$ and $P$ at $(x,y)$ where $0\leq x,y\leq 1$, then complex number for $\angle ABP$, $\angle BCP$, $\angle CDP$, $\angle DAP$ are $1-x+yi$, $1-y+(1-x)i$, $x+(1-y)i$ and $y+xi$ respectively. The product of the four complex numbers is $$z=-x+2x^3-x^4-y+6xy-6x^2y-6xy^2+6x^2y^2+2y^3-y^4+(-x+3x^2-2x^3+y-6x^2y+4x^3y-3y^2+6xy^2+2y^3-4xy^3)i.$$
By the way, I think it's obvious that at least one of the four angles no smaller than $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{4}$, which implies that the sum of the four angles cannot be smaller than $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{4}$. Therefore, if we want to prove $\displaystyle f(P)<\frac{5\pi}{4}$, we just need to prove $\text{Re}(z)-\text{Im}(z)<0$, i.e., \begin{aligned}g(x,y)&=-x + 2  x^3 - x^4 - y + 6  x  y - 6  x^2  y - 6  x  y^2 + 
 6  x^2  y^2 + 
 2  y^3 - y^4 - (-x + 3  x^2 - 2  x^3 \\&+ y - 6  x^2  y + 4  x^3  y - 
   3  y^2 + 6  x  y^2 + 2  y^3 - 4  x  y^3)\\&=-3 x^2 + 4 x^3 - x^4 - 2 y + 6 x y - 4 x^3 y + 3 y^2 - 12 x y^2 + 
 6 x^2 y^2 + 4 x y^3 - y^4\leq 0.\end{aligned}
Proving this becomes another problem, which is not that easy. I tried to prove this without using calculus, but I failed. What I can tell you is that I take partial derivatives for both $x$ and $y$, and I get \begin{aligned}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g&=-6 x + 12 x^2 - 4 x^3 + 6 y - 12 x^2 y - 12 y^2 + 12 x y^2 + 4 y^3\\\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g&=-2 + 6 x - 4 x^3 + 6 y - 24 x y + 12 x^2 y + 12 x y^2 - 4 y^3.\end{aligned} Let both of them be zero, and we have \begin{aligned}&-6 x + 12 x^2 - 4 x^3 + 6 y - 12 x^2 y - 12 y^2 + 12 x y^2 + 4 y^3\\=&-2 + 6 x - 4 x^3 + 6 y - 24 x y + 12 x^2 y + 12 x y^2 - 4 y^3\\=&0,\end{aligned} which implies \begin{aligned}&\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g\\=&2 - 12 x + 12 x^2 + 24 x y - 24 x^2 y - 12 y^2 + 8 y^3\\=&2 (1 - 2  y)(2\sqrt{3}x+2y-\sqrt{3}-1)(2\sqrt{3}x-2y-\sqrt{3}+1)\\=&0.\end{aligned}
Now there're three cases.
(i) $2\sqrt{3}x+2y-\sqrt{3}-1=0$, which means $\displaystyle y=-\sqrt{3}x+\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2}$. Then $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}g=-6 x + 12 x^2 - 4 x^3 + 6 y - 12 x^2 y - 12 y^2 + 12 x y^2 + 4 y^3=4(2x-1)^3=0,$$ which implies $\displaystyle x=y=\frac{1}{2}$.
(ii) $2\sqrt{3}x-2y-\sqrt{3}+1=0$. Using the same method, we can also get $\displaystyle x=y=\frac{1}{2}$.
(iii) $1-2y=0$, which implies $\displaystyle y=\frac{1}{2}$. Plug it into $\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial x}g=0$, and now we have $\displaystyle x=\frac{1}{2}$.
In all of the three cases above, we have $\displaystyle x=y=\frac{1}{2}$. The Hessain matrix is $$\bigg(\begin{matrix}
-6 + 24 x - 12 x^2 - 24 x y + 12 y^2 & 6 - 12 x^2 - 24 y + 24 x y + 12 y^2 \\
6 - 12 x^2 - 24 y + 24 x y + 12 y^2 & 6 - 24 x + 12 x^2 + 24 x y - 12 y^2
\end{matrix}\bigg)\bigg|_{(x,y)=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})}=\bigg(\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{matrix}\bigg),$$ so right now we cannot say that when $\displaystyle (x,y)=\bigg(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\bigg)$, the sum of the four angles has reached its maximum or minimum value, but at least we know $\angle ABP+\angle BCP+\angle CDP+\angle DAP=\pi$ and $\displaystyle g\bigg(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\bigg)=-\frac{1}{4}$.
Fortunately, at this stage we need only to check whether the maximum value can be reached on its boundary, i.e., the four sides of the square. We will first check the situation when $P$ is on the side $AB$. Now $g(x,y)=g(x,0)=4x^3-3x^2-x^4=-x^2(x-1)(x-3)\leq 0$. Similarly, we also have $g(x,y)\leq 0$ on the rest three sides.
Based on what we have got, we can conclude that $g(x,y)\leq 0$ on the entire square plane $\displaystyle [0,1]\times[0,1]$. On the other hand, when $x\to 0^+$ and $y=0$, $\angle ABP+\angle BCP+\angle CDP+\angle DAP$ goes infinitely close to $\displaystyle \frac{5\pi}{4}$. The proof is completed.
However, I think there may be some easier ways to demonstrate this result. Also, I believe I make things too complicated when proving $g(x,y)\leq 0$. There should be one easier method without using calculus. But anyway I give up finding such an easier method because that seems too painful to me.
